# Multilanguage site, subdirectories as language (RewriteRule) WHMCS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I went to make friendly urls for my web using RewriteRule as I'm using whmcs and the script is encoded. Here is what I want:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?language=english
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/en/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^en/(.*)\.html$ /$1.php?language=english [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks it worked put went to redirect visitor who call www.xxx.com/ to www.xxx.com/en or language from cookies and one who try to write .php to .html